# CodeIgniter Static Page Tutorial(Unable to load the requested file)

Tags: php

I've recently downloaded CodeIgniter and install it in XAMPP htdoc -> codeigniter(application,system,user guide,index.php,license.txt)

I've tried to follow with the tutorial posted in CodeIgniter's User Guide on [creating static pages](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/static_pages.html) but I keep getting this error:

Unable to load the requested file: pages/home.php

The controller is at application/controllers/pages.php with the following code:

```
class Pages extends CI_Controller 
{

    public function view($page = 'home')
    {
        if(file_exists('application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
        {
            //whoops we don't have a page for that!
            show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); //Capitalize the first letter
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
    }
}
```

The tutorial also mentioned about creating header.php in application/views/templates/header.php and footer.php in application/views/templates/footer.php, which are just html code and echo out the page title.

And finally also creating a home.php and about.php in application/views/pages/ directory. For home.php and about.php I only type out some plain text.

Where did I go wrong. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. :) Thank you.

Comment: How are you accessing this page? try accessing `domain.com/index.php/pages/home.php`.

Comment: It bring me back to the XAMPP page or just http://localhost.

Comment: I just installed CodeIgniter, am going through their "easy" static page demo, and mine didn't work.  You have to type so many things that it is easy to get a character or two wrong and have it not work.  This pointed me go through my Pages->view class and find my char errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing this line:

```
if(file_exists('application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
```

to this:

```
if(!file_exists( APPPATH . 'views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
```

Comment: Yes, I downloaded and install it according to what they say and I  access the page as in http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/pages/view. Am I doing it the wrong way?

Comment: No. That should be alright, then. What is inside the `/views/pages/` folder? See edited answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! After I change from if(file_exists('application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php')) to if(!file_exists('application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php')) it did not show the error "Unable to load the requested file: pages/home.php" but it show the "404 Page Not Found" cause there's no pages folder. So added pages folder, move the home.php into it and it works. Once again thank you so much!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

can you change this line with

```
if(file_exists('application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
```

something like

```
if(file_exists(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
```

and let me know if that works.

Comment: No, I still get the same error. Unable to load the requested file:pages/home.php

Comment: can you recheck home.php exists in views/pages/ and it's file permissions are 755/777

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I'm running XAMPP on Windows XP.

Comment: is your url in this format [your-site-url]index.php/pages/view  ?

Comment: No, it's http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/pages/view cause I install the CodeIgniter in a folder named codeigniter in the htdocs folder.

Answer (score 1):

In the static page tutorial you are asked to:

> Create a file at application/controllers/pages.php with the following
>   code.

But this won't work since the file name needs to start with a capital like this:

> application/controllers/Pages.php

This did the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

Whether the format is mysite.com/index.php/home or mysite.com/home doesn't matter because it's looking for the view, not the controller.

`if(file_exists('application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))`

should be

`if(!file_exists('application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))`

That isn't what's causing your problem, though. You're showing a 404 when it evaluates to true, which means that the file actually does not exist. If the file existed, you would get a 404 page.

Check thoroughly and make sure you have the file 'application/views/pages/home.php'.

Comment: Nine Hells. I may have never facepalmed this hard before. Never even bothered to double check the logic. You are correct, of course. Good catch.

Comment: Why the facepalm? Your answer caught it too. Either way, that error actually sheds light on the main error in that the file simply doesn't exist. My bet is it's in the wrong folder.